# Timer function calling 2 times javascript and enyo

Tags: javascript, enyo

```
> var index=0;
enyo.kind({
name:"Kapping",
events: {
    onBeat: ""
},
create : function(){
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this.timer = window.setInterval(enyo.bind(this,"beat"),1000);
},
destroy : function(){
    if(this.timer != undefined){
        window.clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
    this.inherited(arguments);
},
beat: function(){
    this.doBeat({
        //this.fetch();
    });
    index = index+1;
    console.log('Doing beat ' + index);
}
```

});
/*

new Kapping().renderInto(document.body);

In which `beat` function is getting called 2 times.
and another one is

```
> var i =0;
enyo.kind({
name:"Heartbeat",
events: {
    onBeat: ""
},
create : function(){
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this.timer = window.setInterval(enyo.bind(this,"beat"),1000);
},
destroy : function(){
    if(this.timer != undefined){
        window.clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
    this.inherited(arguments);
},
beat: function(){
    this.doBeat({
    });
    i=i+1;
    console.log("In timer callback " + i);
}
});

new Heartbeat().renderInto(document.body);
```

In this `beat` function is getting called only once.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run only once then you want `setTimeout()` not `setInterval()`.

I'm not sure why you see different behavior but it is probably a timing issue as both samples run forever for me. Perhaps there is a problem elsewhere in your code.